# How to parallelly process a pandas Dataframe for each unique value in a column?

Tags: pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, joblib

I'm looking for ideas to optimize my function. I have limited knowledge on multiprocessing so just looking for someone to point me in the right direction!

So, I have a pandas DataFrame with the following format

```
---------------------------------------------------
|Date         | Portfolio | Classification | P&L  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2016-01-01  | A         | Class_1        | 100  |
--------------------------------------------------
|2016-01-02   | A         | Class_2        | 200  |
.                                                 .
.                                                 .  
.                                                 .
--------------------------------------------------
|2019-10-31   | A         | Class_700      | -200 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

All I need to get from this is P&L attribution that basically explains how each unique Class generated p&l from its inception & I have another function to do that...

Currently my logic is:

```
for unique_class in df['Classification'].unique():
    class_df = df[df['Classification'] == unique_class].copy()
    result1, result2 = call_attribution_function(class_df)
    overall_results1.append(result1)
    overall_results2.append(results2)
```

This gets the job done but is obviously very slow. In real scenario, I have over 700 unique classifications.
However, none of the classifications are dependent on each other. Basically all 700 can be processed parallelly and that would significantly improve the performance.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?
I've seen a few examples with **joblib**   but I didn't get a lot of direction for slicing dataframes and parallelizing functions with multiple return variables..

Any pointers highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's `call_attribution_function`?

Comment: its just a function that has all the logic for doing the attribution.
It requires a timeseries dataframe for individual classifications levels

Comment: Generally speaking, you can do `df.groupby('Classification').apply(df.groupby('Classification').apply(call_attribute_function)`. However, one should try to process `call_attribution_function` using pandas/numpy's vectorized functions, on the dataframe level.

Comment: Can't do vectorization in that because part of that function is taking a cumulative sum, cumulative prod etc

Comment: That's why I asked you should describe what you are trying to do with `call_attribution_function`, `pd.DataFrame.cumsum()` and `pd.DataFrame.cumprod()` are vectorized.

Comment: Hmm...also the data frame is further sliced into YTD, QTD, MTD etc dates and then cumulative sum is performed!

Comment: Again, all of those sound very much vectorizable.